# What difference between delimiter $$ and //

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

Usually I use of `delimiter // trigger //` to prevent of stop after a semicolon `;`. But there is an other delimiter that uses of `$$`, I want to know what is difference between them ?! When, should I use of which one ?

Comment: depends on your mood

Comment: @Drew So actually there is not any difference ?

Comment: if you are really upset, maybe !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

> [19.1 Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)
>
> You can redefine the delimiter to a string other than //, and the delimiter can consist of a single character or multiple characters. You should avoid the use of the backslash (“\”) character because that is the escape character for MySQL.